# define pair of iterator in template class with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

how can i define
pair of iterator in template class with template parameter

```
template <typename S,typename T>
class pairMove :public pair<S,T>
{

private:
    pair< multimap<S,T>::iterator , multimap<S,T>::iterator > pairIt;
```

i get this error in compile time

> //Error   2 error C2923: 'std::pair' : 'std::multimap::iterator' is
>   not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty1'

any solution to resolve my problem

Answer (score 6):

You miss the `typename` keyword:

```
pair<typename multimap<S,T>::iterator, typename multimap<S,T>::iterator> pairIt;
     ^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Note that, `S` and `T` are `template` types; and when they are used in combination with `::` operator to get another dependent type, one has to use `typename`.

Another [nice discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) about this topic.